# Attempting to change next and previous slick slider arrows based on what slide is currently active

Tags: jquery

I have my slick slider setup correctly, and its working nicely.

I have also given each slide a specific id,

```
ex: <a id="education" href="www.test.com">
```

From looking at the how slick slider functions. I have 3 slides currently. When each slide is the one in view (or in focus might be a better word). Slick gives the slide a class of "slick-active" and "slick-current".

In a simple world I would just write a basic jquery if/else statement to check if the slide I want has the class of slick-active. If it does, I want a class added to another element.

So my jquery currently:

```
function sliderChange() {

 console.log('slider change ready');

 if ( $("#education").hasClass('slick-active') ) {
    alert('education got the class');
 }

}
```

The way the slides are setup in HTML

```
<a id="education" href="/education" class="link" style="background-image:url(/content/1-home/legal.png)">
</a>
```

'slick-active' is added to the the "link" class whenever the slider is activated. But it seems that my sliderChange() function is running, but however slick is changing the classes it isn't reflecting that inside my jQuery. I presume however they are doing it is ignoring the DOM setting thus ignoring my function?

My aim is to change the colour of the next/previous buttons to white from current css class once that specific slide is in focus. If i can get the jquery to pickup on the class change I am confident i can do the rest myself.

Any help is massively appreciated. For a simple function it is quite annoying ^^

Comment: I think you might be better posting this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Do you want it in a specific slide (#education) or in an active slide? And how are you calling the SliderChange() ?

Comment: Im calling the sliderChange() inside a routing function that gets run on initial page load